# Angular: Subscribe is not called after successful web request

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, graphql, rxjs6

I have an angular ionic app with graphql. I Updated from angular 8 to 9 to 10 to 11. The migrations were successful and my app does transpile.

But if I try to execute the following request via apollo the subsribe method is not called but the web request return with a 200. I can see it inside the browser and can see the log of my application server. I do not know why this piece of code is not executed.

```
     this.apollo.mutate({
                mutation: gql`
                    mutation Test {
                        test
                    }
                `
            }).subscribe(({data}) => {
                console.log('got data', data);
            });
```

These are my dependency imports inside the file that tries to call the mutation:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import {UserService} from "./services/user.service";
import {TranslateService} from "@ngx-translate/core";
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {ImageService} from './services/image.service';
import {NgEventBus} from 'ng-event-bus';
import {Events} from './events/events';
import {User} from './entities/user.entity';
import {Apollo, gql} from 'apollo-angular';
```

This are my dependencies inside the project. I have already checked that my node_modules only contain these dependencies with deleting the folder and run npm install. If I create a new project everythin works fine and as expected.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1102.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.5",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.11",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.6.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "apollo-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "ng-event-bus": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.6",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.7",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-angular": "^2.3.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.33",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your Dev Console?  Maybe like a CORS error.

Comment: @BizzyBob OP states that web request returns 200.

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point and stepping into the mutate code?

Comment: Is it possible this mutation code is duplicated somewhere else?  Maybe try commenting it out and see if call still gets dispatched.  Seems silly, but I really can't see why subscribe would not receive emission.  But, maybe there is a bug in ApolloClient.

Comment: If I setup a new project with the these dependencies the mutation emits the subscribe. If I use the apollo.query method the query still gets executed and I receive 200. But the subscribe is not called. If I use the watchQuery method from apollo the subscribe works as intended.